Method to create summary-of-summaries of a k6 multi-instance test
When using 10 separate k6 instances (NOT on Grfana's cloud service), I'm getting 10 different summaries. Is there any way to combine them into one grand summary?

Might be useful: https://grafana.com/blog/2022/06/23/running-distributed-load-tests-on-kubernetes/

Thanks, but this operator was my first attempt. Unfortunately, it explicitly doesn't provide this facility - see "Metrics will not be automatically aggregated by default" in the post. I was trying to avoid a 3rd party metrics collector (but I may end up doing it).
